# Sentence vectors for fasttext

Tags: fasttext

I tried for creating sentence vectors in fasttext for a single line in english in python, but all i got was solution related to CLI in fasttext.

[Link for fast test sentence vector creation](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText)

I want a function or a library that can easily provide me sentence vector for the input sentence in an english text form that I can use it in my python script.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! I noticed your question doesn't show what the error is. You say "all i got was solution related to CLI in fasttext." That's fine, but include what you're actually seeing. If it's not an error code, take a screen-shot and attach it to your post. Also include the code you tried: you say "I tried creating sentence vectors in fasttext for a single line." Be sure to include what that line is. Also see [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to make your question more readable. This will help get your question answered asap. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

This one:

https://pypi.org/project/fasttext/

Then we just need to average or sum output vectors for each token in a sentence.